# how to handle mongooe validation error and procced further on basis of error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i have built user schema in mongoose for validation of error and its working correctly but how to handle those error and as i want to proceed further on basis of those error in my project

```
const userSchema = {
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min:10
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    min: 5,
    required: true
  }
};
```

the error i am getting

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: email: Path `email` is required.
```

Comment: Could you add the code which throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

based on [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) you can do like this

```
const assert = require('assert');
const userSchema  = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'required email'],
    min: [6, 'min email']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    min: [5, 'min password'],
    required: [true, 'required password']
  }
});
const User = db.model('User', userSchema);

const user = new User({
  email: "a@gmail.com",
  bacon: 123,
});
let error = user.validateSync();

assert.equal(error.errors['email'].message,'required email');
assert.ok(!error.errors['email']);
assert.equal(error.errors['email'].message,
  'min email');
```

**Note**:but it's better for validation of input Data use **[joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi)** module